# Validate Vtiger CRM 6.2 fields (Of a Custom Module) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, crm, vtiger

I have a custom module I created via the ModuleDesigner tool called 'CDP'.

I am looking to make some field validations in CDP before saving a record.

How can I do that? I prefer not to use a handler.

Since CDP is a custom module, there is no /layouts/vlayout/modules/CDP/ directory (and subsequently, no /resources/Edit.js file)

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks!
Sam

Answer (score 0):

You can create it if needed.

But not sure using Edit.js to make validation is the better choice because nothing avoid to save the record even if your validation rule fail except if you use recordPresaveEvent

Otherwise you can use addMethod in order to validate your field like it's done for mandatories f

Comment: Hello Jeremy, thanks for your answer. I tried creating the directories and Edit.js file inside vlayout but it is not getting anywhere. Reason I prefer JS is to interact with user. but I also tried creating a recordPresaveEvent. I see the handler DB registers, but for some reason the handler is not triggered. My PHP code has no errors in Syntax) and I just tried a simple redirect but nothing happens.